# Countdown Widget

Tags: widgets

Can someone recommend me a nice countdown widget plugin for Wordpress?
I've been using the Countdown widget under Blogger and it's exactly what I need. A simple number from now until date or from date.
I can't seem to find a very simple, easy countdown that does the same thing in Wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's a great widget called the [jQuery T-Minus Countdown Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jquery-t-countdown-widget/screenshots/)

Enjoy!

Comment: Wow, that's really easy to use. Can't believe I missed this one. Thanks!